# How to get PKCS11 PublicKey via Template

Tags: go, cryptography, pkcs#11, elliptic-curve, hsm

I have a GO Application, that stores it's certificate to a HSM via opencryptoki (pkcs11) in a softwaretoken. But it's not a go question, more a general pkcs11 question I think.

I set my certificates and privatekey like this:

```
    certTemplate := []*pkcs11.Attribute{
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_CLASS, pkcs11.CKO_CERTIFICATE),
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_CERTIFICATE_TYPE, pkcs11.CKC_X_509),
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_TOKEN, true),
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_VALUE, certBytes),
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_SUBJECT, template.SubjectKeyId),
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_ID, pkcs11KeyID),
    }

    privateKeyTemplate := []*pkcs11.Attribute{
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_CLASS, pkcs11.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY),
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_KEY_TYPE, pkcs11.CKK_ECDSA),
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_TOKEN, true), 
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_ID, pkcs11KeyID),
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_EC_PARAMS, []byte{0x06, 0x08, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0xce, 0x3d, 0x03, 0x01, 0x07}),
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_VALUE, ecdsaPrivKeyD),
    }

ctx.CreateObject(session, certTemplate)
ctx.CreateObject(session, privateKeyTemplate)
```

This works perfectly. I can also get the Certificate via

```
findTemplate := []*pkcs11.Attribute{
    pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_TOKEN, true),
    pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_CLASS, pkcs11.CKO_CERTIFICATE),
    pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_CERTIFICATE_TYPE, pkcs11.CKC_X_509),
}

ctx.FindObjectsInit(session, findTemplate); 
objs, b, err := ctx.FindObjects(session, numSlots)
```

But I cannot get my public key, as I expected

```
findTemplate := []*pkcs11.Attribute{
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_TOKEN, true),
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_ID, pkcs11KeyID),
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_CLASS, pkcs11.CKO_PUBLIC_KEY),
    }
ctx.FindObjectsInit(session, findTemplate); 
obj, _, err := ctx.FindObjects(session, 1)
```

There is no error, just that there are no keys in the hsm store.

Comment: If you can get the certificate, then you can parse it and get the public key (it's part of the information included in the certificate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the public key is part of the certificate, the `CKO_PUBLIC_KEY` object may not be separately available, and there isn't a `CKA_PUBLIC` attribute either for certificates.

To get to the public key you'll have to retrieve the `CKA_VALUE` of the certificate and parse it using your favorite X.509v3 certificate parser. The result will undoubtedly return either the encoded public key value or a public key as structure in your favorite runtime.

Answer (score 4):

As you have already written in your question, you have created/imported only two persistent token objects - certificate object (`CKA_CLASS = CKO_CERTIFICATE`) and private key object (`CKA_CLASS = CKO_PRIVATE_KEY`) - so naturally you can find only these two objects by calling `FindObjectsInit` and `FindObjects`.

If you want to find also a public key object (`CKA_CLASS = CKO_PUBLIC_KEY`) then you will need to create/import it first.

Comment: But the public key is part of the certificate, no?

Comment: @Florian Yes it is, but PKCS#11 does not parse or interpret certificate value in any other way then just store it.